# WiiU Bundle is missing a game

Tags: wii-u

I recently purchased my son a WiiU since he broke the last one, and it is supposed to have Smash Bros and Splatoon pre-installed, but I don't see Smash Bros.

Where would it be?

Comment: How do you know it has smash bros if you don't see it?

Comment: It has it on the box it was a bundle deal with both games suppose to be on it

Comment: @Frank [Must be this bundle](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/nintendo-wii-u-32gb-smash-splat-special-edition-deluxe-console-set-black/4628609.p?id=1219780990830&skuId=4628609)

Comment: @Wipqozn Yeah, just found it.  Huh.  Where'd you get it from?

Comment: @QuenteaOliver [Couple folks talking about it here](https://www.reddit.com/r/wiiu/comments/3txzp2/preinstalled_games_question/). Should just be on the WiiU. If you don't see it them in the main menu then you might want to reach out to nintendo customer service.

Comment: @QuenteaOliver By chance, what happened to the broken one?  Nintendo offers a repair service that would would be able to repair (or if not, replace) the broken system, leaving the preinstalled games there.

Comment: Sometimes you only have one game pre-installed, the other one comes with a download code.

Comment: @NBN-Alex The edit does not reflect the original question. The question is about the game on the *new* system, not the old one

Comment: I purchased it off amazon and it said new

Comment: Who was the seller?